# Set cookie after output without ob_start

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, ob-start

I'm guessing not, but is there a way to set a cookie in PHP without having to put `ob_start()` at the start of the output?

My problem is, that I am developing a class, which among others, needs to set a cookie. Now I can't tell the person who uses it "you have to make a new instance of the class before you make any output", cause that would be lame. So can I somehow pull it off?

Comment: Why is it lame to set a cookie before output?

Comment: It's not lame to do so if it's your code, it's just lame to force another developer to do so because he wants to use your class.

Comment: If you document that the class is responsible for sending HTTP headers (like Set-Cookie), there's nothing wrong with saying that it needs to be used before any output is sent. That's exactly what the `setcookie` documentation says, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Headers already sent by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

The unprofessional workarounds listed there apply. Specifically:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Set-Cookie" 
CONTENT="cookievalue=xy;expires=Friday, 14-Dec-12 12:12:12 GMT; path=/">
```

Or use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and set `document.cookie`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Cookies are sent as part of the header, so if you've already sent the body, it's too late. Output buffering is the solution.

Perhaps you could use session variables instead.

Comment: I will probably do that only in the case the cookie cannot be set, so thanks, this is a good suggestion too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my workround and is working fine for me.

```
// Force set cookie now
$_COOKIE['ref_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// Set cookie after refresh site
setcookie('ref_url', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], Affiliate::$cookieTime);

// Diplay $_COOKIE
var_dump($_COOKIE['ref_url']);
```

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is sometimes empty, so test it up first before using it.
$url_referrer = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])?'':$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];